# Word Wrap - VSCode

Tags: html, web, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, alguien me da una mano con una config de vscode?. resulta que tengo activado la opcion de word wrap, que lo que hace es cambiar de linea una vez llegada al final de la ventana, pero esta no respeta la identacion inicial, es decir la de la linea anterior. Se que esto se puede corregir con Prettier (aunque no funciona en los comentarios) o algun formateador, pero he visto que se puede tener de manera automatica esto. Alguien sabria como configurar o que tendria que hacer para que se respetara los identados?

Comment: verifica si es esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51318131/22473069